# shutdown suddenly gone (win7)

Tags: command-line, windows-7, cmd, shutdown

I'm having a wired problem for a few days now.

Usually I just type:

```
shutdown -s -t 123456
```

but it says this **command does not exist**. So I googled a bit and found:

```
shutdown /s /t 123456
```

same problem.

I tried writing it in caps or just uppercase S but no luck. The shutdown.exe in sys32 is 34kb large.

```
sfc /scannow
sfc -scannow
```

also shows the same error.

At least the cd command still works. I am not aware that I did anything special to my system.

Any ideas?

Comment: You broke your system PATH. Type `set PATH` at a command prompt, and check the entries. You'll find that Windows\System32 is not in the path.

Comment: The default path on Windows 7 should be `C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\`

Answer (score 0):

There is a high chance that the system PATH was broken. Like what @Ken White said, type `set PATH` in `cmd.exe` and check the entries. If `Windows\System32` is not in the path, then it is broken.

To fix this, go to `Computer > right click on Computer > Properties > Advanced system settings > Advanced (tab) > Environment Variables`. In the 2nd box (System variables), find the variable `Path`. Click on it and then click `Edit`. Under `Variable value`, add the following **after** the long string:

```
;%SystemRoot%\system32
```

Leave the `;` there as this will split up the paths. You might need to restart your computer for the change to take effect.

Hope it helps :)